# nested form not displaying in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, nested-attributes

I have a form for a model called isp, which 'has_many' isp accounts. the isp account belongs to to 'isp'.

There is a validation on the isp_account that means it cant be added if there isnt an isp_id, so my reasoning is to created a nested form. I created the nested form like so

```
= simple_form_for @isp, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.simple_fields_for :isp_accounts do |tag|
    = tag.input :title, label: "Tag Name"
```

however the nested attribute isnt being displayed. There are no errors etc. Why is this? Am I approaching this in the best way? is this the only way?

here's the code

ISP MODEL

```
class Isp < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :isp_accounts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :deployments, through: :servers
  has_many :servers, through: :isp_accounts
  validates :title, presence: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :isp_accounts


end
```

ISP ACCOUNTS MODEL

```
class IspAccount < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :isp
  has_many :deployments, through: :servers
  has_many :servers, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true
  validate :check_associates

  private

  def check_associates
    associated_object_exists Isp, :isp_id
  end
end
```

ISP ACCOUNT CONTROLLER

```
    ....
    def new
        @isp_account = IspAccount.new
    end

    def update
    @isp_account.update_attributes(isp_accounts_path)
    if @isp_account.save
      record_saved
      return redirect_to(isp_accounts_path)
    else
      check_for_errors
      return render('/isp_accounts/edit')
    end
  end

    private

    def get_isp_accounts
        @isp_account = IspAccount.all
    end

    def get_isp_account
        @isp_account = IspAccount.find(params_isp_accounts)
    end
    def params_isp_accounts
    params.require(:isp_account).permit!
  end
end

....
  def new
    @isp = Isp.new
  end

  def update
    @isp.update_attributes(params_isp)
    if @isp.save
      record_saved
      return redirect_to(isps_path)
    else
      check_for_errors
      return render('new')
    end
  end

  private 

  def params_isp
    params.require(:isp).permit(:title, isp_accounts_attributes: [:id, :title])
  end

  def get_isp
    @isp = Isp.where(id: params[:id]).first
    unless @isp
      record_not_found
      return redirect_to(isps_path)
    end
  end

  def get_isps
    @isp = Isp.all.order(:title)
  end
end
```

SCHEMA

```
create_table "isp_accounts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "isp_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "isps", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got it. I was missing the new bit for that attribute in my controller. pretty basic really.

```
def new
   @isp = Isp.new
   @isp.isp_accounts.new
 end
```